# Click on second element with CasperJS

Tags: xpath, css-selectors, click, casperjs

I want to use CasperJS to click over the second element in a document.

**My Document:**

```
<div class="sample secondClass">1</div>
<div class="sample">2
  <ul class="ul">
    <li class="li">
      <a class="link">
        <div class="div_msg">
          <span>AbCde</span>
        </div>    
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
<div class="sample secondClass">3</div>
```

**This is what I have tried:**

```
casper.thenClick(x('//*[@class="sample"][2]/ul[@class="ul"]/li[@class="li"]/a[@class="link"]/div[@class="div_msg"]/span[string-length(text())="ABCDE"]'), function() {
  ...
  //do anythings
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x(...)` is a convenience function to use XPath expressions with almost all CasperJS functions instead of CSS selectors. `:nth-child(1)` is a CSS selector, that doesn't work in XPath expressions.

You can select the position of an element among its matched siblings with `[x]`. If you want the second element, then use `x('//*[@class="sample"][2]')` (XPaths and CSS selectors are 1-indexed and not 0-index like basically all other programming languages).

```js
colorMatchingRed('//*[@class="sample"][2]')

function colorMatchingRed(xpath) { 
    var spans = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null); 
    for (var i = 0 ; i < spans.snapshotLength; i++ ) spans.snapshotItem(i).style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="sample">No</div>
    <div class="sample">Yes</div>
    <div class="sample">No</div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div>
    <div>No</div>
    <div class="sample">No</div>
    <div class="sample">Yes</div>
    <div class="sample">No</div>
</div>
```

You can also use `x('//*[@class="sample" and position()=2]')` which has a slightly different meaning, because it matches the second element among its siblings that also has a specific `@class` attribute.

```js
colorMatchingRed('//*/*[@class="sample" and position()=2]')

function colorMatchingRed(xpath) { 
    var spans = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null); 
    for (var i = 0 ; i < spans.snapshotLength; i++ ) spans.snapshotItem(i).style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="sample">No</div>
    <div class="sample">Yes</div>
    <div class="sample">No</div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div>
    <div>No</div>
    <div class="sample">Yes</div>
    <div class="sample">No</div>
    <div class="sample">No</div>
</div>
```

If the elements are not siblings of one another, then you can also evaluate the node set and select a specific element from that set: `x('(//*[@class="sample"])[2]')`. It creates a set of all elements with that specific @class and chooses the second one.

```js
colorMatchingRed('(//*[@class="sample"])[2]')

function colorMatchingRed(xpath) { 
    var spans = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null); 
    for (var i = 0 ; i < spans.snapshotLength; i++ ) spans.snapshotItem(i).style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="sample">No</div>
    <div class="sample">Yes</div>
    <div class="sample">No</div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div>
    <div>No</div>
    <div class="sample">No</div>
    <div class="sample">No</div>
    <div class="sample">No</div>
</div>
```

---

Here's the correct click call for the updated question:

```
casper.thenClick(x('//*[@class="sample"][2]/ul[@class="ul"]/li[@class="li"]/a[@class="link"]/div[@class="div_msg"]/span[string-length(text())=string-length("ABCDE")]'), ...)
```

or shorter:

```
casper.thenClick(x('//*[@class="sample"][2]//div[@class="div_msg"]/span[string-length(text())=string-length("ABCDE")]'), ...)
```

Comment: Then the markup is different than what you're shown in your question. Run the example scripts in my answer to see that they indeed work.

Comment: We did this dance before. You've asked a severely reduced question, gotten an answer, but it turned out your problem was more complicated than that. You can edit your question and we will see if it invalidates my answer.

Comment: `string-length()` produces a number, but you're comparing that to a string. Perhaps you wanted to use `span[string-length(text())=string-length("ABCDE")]`

Comment: No, I don't have one. I've looked into their security and it's not that good.

Comment: Well, didn't this help?

Comment: I've just tried it and my suggestion works with the code you've presented in your updated question. Here's an XPath tutorial: http://zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html

Comment: Please answer me complete, together click function.